# icon changes the position on selection of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, tableview

I have a prototype cell. When the table view controller is opened for the first time. the cell looks like this:

[image]

Question #1: I have a constraint that the `leading space to superview` of calendar icon should be 10 points. but in reality it's 16 points.

Then very strange thing happens. I click on the cell. It goes to the next screen. Then I come back to this screen. And the icon is positioned correctly (10points space):

[image]

Then what happens next is: if i click on the cell, for a very short moment (when highlighted) the icon moves to the right for 6 points:

[image]

Question #2: how to avoid this 'moving' ?

What I tried to do: added these 2 lines to didSelectRowAtIndexPath and willSelectRowAtIndexPath
`cell?.setNeedsLayout()
 cell?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`

But it doesn't help much.. Please let me know if you need more details. Btw, I have no code that changes any constraints. Everything is static.

**EDIT:** this is how constraints of icon (imageView) looks like:

[image]

note: `leading space to superview` equals to `2` because it has some default of 8 (so 2+8=10).

Comment: Fam Have you taken any view on your cell to add all these labels?

Comment: @TusharSharma i'm not sure if i understood your question. though i think my answer is 'no' :)

Comment: It will help more if you post some useful code here.

Comment: @aircraft thanks! what code do you want to see? please kindly let me know. on didSelectRow i just do 'perform segue' ..

Comment: @Tung Fam, how do you create the cell? use xib or what?

Comment: @aircraft in the prototype cell (inside table view).

Answer (score 0):

Please adapt and try my code. Before register this cell

```
tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

and initialize

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
```

======

```
class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 56, y: (textLabel?.frame.origin.y)! - 2, width: (textLabel?.frame.width)!, height: (textLabel?.frame.height)!)
    detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 56, y: (detailTextLabel?.frame.origin.y)! + 2, width: (detailTextLabel?.frame.width)!, height: (detailTextLabel?.frame.height)!)

}
let profileImagView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()



override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(profileImagView)
    profileImagView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor,constant:8).isActive  = true
    profileImagView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImagView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    profileImagView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I have not tried through the  xib, however I think it makes sense